# cant load bitmap TIFF image to a matrix

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmap

I would like to load an image to a matrix in order to do some calculations,I have found a way to load it
here
is the matrix

```
private static Color[,] matrix;
```

```
 public async void Initiate_Matrix()//
        {
            FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker
            {
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
            };
            fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tif");
            fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            var inputFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (inputFile == null)
            {
                // The user cancelled the picking operation
                return;
            }
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // Create the decoder from the stream
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                var bytes = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
                var a = decoder.PixelWidth;
                var b = decoder.PixelHeight;
                Color[,] array = new Color[a, b];
                for (int x = 0; x < decoder.PixelWidth; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < decoder.PixelHeight; y++)
                    {
                        var location = (y * (int)decoder.PixelWidth + x) * 3;
                        Color color = Color.FromArgb(0, bytes[location + 0], bytes[location + 1], bytes[location + 2]);
                        array[x, y] = color;
                    }
                }
                matrix = array;
            }
        }
```

but it seems that every time that I try I get this exception  `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.`

Comment: I can’t reproduce your issue. After testing, your code works well. Could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub for testing?

Comment: I ran this code again but this time I picked a smaller image and it worked. the image  size of my required picture is 33 mb. so I think  the problem is about the size of the image.

Comment: There may not be enough memory space to allocate some of the larger objects used by your project. You could try to use [MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusage?view=winrt-19041) to get the app's current memory usage and [MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit?view=winrt-19041) to the app's memory usage limit .